# Angular 1.x : Specific Scenario When To Use Controller / Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

Let's say, In a web app, a particular JSON is frequently used across multiple pages, for e.g:

```
 {
    "employees":[
       {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
       {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
       {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
     ]
 }
```

So getting a `firstName()` or `lastName()` for all employees should be considered as a part of the controller or the Service?

I could only think of using **services** as it is frequently used across app and controller be getting this data and it will be thinner too.

Is this right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have following options:**

> 1. Make a REST/HTTP call every time you need this data in a certain controller. Therefore, create a EmployeesService which calls the HTTP
>      endpoint to get the data.
> 2. Call the data once, and store it in a service. Afterwards, inject the service everywhere you need the data.
> 3. Fetch the data from the HTTP endpoint when your app starts, and store it in the local storage of the browser or inside the $rootScope,
>      so you can access it from everywhere.

In the end, it depends on:

- How big is your app/how much data you have to share?
- How often gets this data updated?
- Which Views do need access to this data?

So yes, with a service, you are on a safe side. Afterwards, inject it into the controller and use it from there. How and how often the data gets into the service: Your decision.

Comment: Presently, I am using a tiny service to return data from end point but since the multiple controllers is defining these methods again and again , I thought to include these methods in the service layer so that it can be shared across controllers.

Unfortunately, I can't use 'localStorage' because of the legacy support.

This data is a big piece of data and including all logic in controller , becomes heavy.